# Only allow certain roles to publish content, other roles can save as unpublished?

Tags: 8, users

I have a Content Admin and a Translator Roles.

Content Admin's can create, edit, delete, and publish content (this is working fine)

Translator's shouldn't be allowed to publish content, they should only be able to create and edit translations. (it should save as unpublished).

Anyone know how to achieve what I'm trying to do in Drupal 8? Or know if a module that does this has been ported to Drupal 8?

Comment: You need a module for that for sure.

Comment: Looks like you will have to custom module it until a stable Rules is out.

Comment: If it was like D7 where you checkbox something to be published, it would be as easy as using hook_node_presave and then checking or unchecking the box. But since D8 is totally different with those 2 buttons, idk how to approach this.

Comment: I found an interesting discussion worth noting. [Change "Save and keep un-/published" buttons to a "Published" checkbox and an included "Save" button](https://www.drupal.org/node/2068063)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to alter insert / update node entity form:

1. Define a permission "Save unpublished content"
2. Make a hook_form_alter or hook_form_ENTITY_TYPE_form_alter
3. Check if you are alter the exact entity types you need.
4. Hide all buttons you don't need (based on permission)
5. Add button ('save unpublished content') (based on persmission)
6. When submitting: call the default submission and add yours to set the status 0.

Save button is an UL with two LI elements: save published, save unpublished: